# TestFlight [ios] app just black screens and doesn't work

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm using the builtin testflight app with iOS for my gamemaker game and it just doesn't work.  I've uploaded a binary and selected a build and when a user goes to install and open it the screen flashes black then exits.

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: did you add LaunchImage in your app?

Comment: gamemaker provides a launch image i believe.  that should come up when running tests in xcode, no?

Comment: I received an email that said this:

Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement...

Comment: Sorry this might sound stupid but what is gamemaker? Is this your app or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your Run Scheme is set to "Release" not "Debug"

Answer (score 0):

Okay 2 things seem to be contributing to the problem here:
1) Gamemaker isn't compatible with iOS8 yet.  Or at least it's not stable.
2) I was using a wildcard provisioning profile, which doesn't include some permissions necessary for Testflight.